# Dialog for fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Why is my `showPopup` grey when I already have an `OnClick` method on that fragment's xml?

I'm trying to make the `popup_about_app` XML popup when I click on the button with the `OnClick`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myDialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
}

public void showPopup(View view) {
    TextView txtclose;

    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_about_app);
    txtclose =(TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClose);
    txtclose.setText("X");

    txtclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, gray means its not being used yet.  Either nothing is calling showPopup, or possibly that Android Studio isn't smart enough to find the thing calling showPopup (which can happen in various scenarios). I wouldn't worry about it unless you hit the button that's supposed to call showPopup and nothing happens (and then it means you forgot to call it).  If the popup shows like you expect, its a non-issue.

Comment: showPopup is an onclick method, however it crashes when I tap on the button.

Comment: Post the logcat of the crash and the code where you set the onclick if you want help on that.